# Any and All sql clause

Tags: sql-server

```
select id 
from master_tabe 
where id = ALL (select id from user_table where name = 'Nikhil')

select id 
from master_tabe 
where id = ANY (select id from user_table where name = 'Nikhil')
```

Above mentioned queries are returning the same resultset. According to my knowledge there should be different resultset as the user_table has only one record related to name Nikhil. So according to this Any clause must return 1 row whereas All must return 0 records. Whereas when I add one more record in user_table than All clause statement is returning 0 rows and Any clause is returning only 1 row.

Can someone look into this?

Comment: You probably only have a single user with the name `Nikhil`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added one more record with same name but All clause statement is returning 0 records in that case whereas Any clause is still returning 1 record.

Comment: [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms178543%28v%3dsql.105%29) - returns TRUE only when ALL values returned by subquery matches (for example, if subq returns 2 or more different IDs, or one of IDs is NULL, then the result is always FALSE). [ANY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175064%28v%3dsql.105%29) - returns TRUE when at least one (not all) of values returned by subquery matches.

Comment: *the user_table has only one record related to name Nikhil. So according to this Any clause must return 1 row whereas All must return 0 records.* No. Both will return the same result when subq returns one record only. *when I add one more record in user_table than All clause statement is returning 0 rows and Any clause is returning only 1 row.* That's true when this second record have `ID` value which differs from that in existing record. Otherwise the result will be the same again.

Comment: Another variant.  ALL - returns FALSE when at least one of values returned by subquery not matches. ANY - returns TRUE when at least one of values returned by subquery matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result you've got return seems very normal to me.

[ANY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/some-any-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will return TRUE when at least one value returned by the subquery compares positively. 
Logically, you could compare this to using multiple OR statements, one OR comparison for each value returned by the subquery.

[ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/all-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on the other hand requires each value returned by the subquery to compare positively. 
Logically, you could compare this to using multiple AND statements, one AND statement for each value returned by the subquery.

You stated that the subquery originally returned a single record. Therefore it didn't matter whether you used ALL or ANY. As soon as you added another record, there is a difference though. At that moment there are multiple values (ID's) in the subquery to compare to and they will **logically** be evaluated as OR/AND statements

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tbl (ID int)   
GO  

INSERT dbo.Tbl VALUES (1),(2),(3)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.SubTbl (ID int)   
GO  

INSERT dbo.SubTbl VALUES (1),(2)
GO


SELECT ID
FROM dbo.Tbl 
WHERE ID = ANY(SELECT ID FROM dbo.SubTbl)
GO

-- Has the same result as ANY:
SELECT ID
FROM dbo.Tbl 
WHERE ID = 1 OR ID = 2
GO

SELECT ID
FROM dbo.Tbl 
WHERE ID = ALL(SELECT ID FROM dbo.SubTbl)
GO

-- Has the same result as ALL:
SELECT ID
FROM dbo.Tbl 
WHERE ID = 1 AND ID = 2
GO
```